# Reading an input with space in c++

Tags: c++, string, input

currently I am doing to read input with spaces in it.

```
int main() {
  char str[100];
  string st;
  cin.getline(str,100);
  st=str;
}
```

I want to utilize the functions that come along with the string, so I am reading the input into a string. Is there any other way to read the input directly into the string which also allow space.

Comment: Use `std::string` and `std::getline`.

Comment: also you can do `cin >> st;` -- it reads string until whitespace
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operator%3E%3E/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to use `std::string` objects, just use `std::getline`.

```
std::string st;
std::getline(std::cin, st);
```

Answer (score -1):

using gets () function.

It accepts even space as input.

Eg. )

```
gets (variable_name);
```

Comment: -1 gets() is a great way to introduce security vulnerabilities, besides that OP asks how to read directly in a std::string